# How do I install tar 1.20?

Tags: 10.04, apt, versions

I have tar 1.22 installed and I need tar 1.20. I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install tar=1.20
```

but I got:

> Version '1.20' for 'tar' was not found

When I looked more closely it turned out that the current version is not just `1.22`, but `1.22-2ubuntu1`. So I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install tar=1.20-2ubuntu1
```

But still got the that error message.

Any idea how do I install tar 1.20 on my Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Hardy, the long term version from 2008 has 1.19. I know it is not the same as 1.20 but I guess it is the closest you can get using canonicals blessed bits. Try to download the three files from the right side of this page: http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/tar and use `dpkg-buildpackage` to make a package suitable for your distribution. After that, you need to force the installation with `dpkg -f -i` because you're probably downgrading.

I am left wondering why would you do such a thing. Is 1.22 giving you a hard time?

Answer (score 1):

If it is not in the repositories and you can't find any PPA for it then you'll have to build from source.

You can get the source [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/).

Answer (score 0):

You should try `sudo apt-get install tar=1.22-2ubuntu1`, rather than `sudo apt-get install tar=1.20-2ubuntu1`, because those are different versions.  Note that the latest version may not be included in the repositories for your version of Ubuntu, in which case, get the source from the link given by Octavian here, and you can then build it from source.